# Dual language management in lotus application

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-designer

good morning. 
Is there a fast way to allow a user who opens a form with his lotus client to switch from one language to another, as happens in all web applications?  I could think of a whole series of hide-when on all labels, but I'm afraid it would weigh down the application, are there other ways?
PS: I don't care about the web part, only the client side!

Comment: Yes there are a LOT of ways to do this... This question is far to broad for being answered... For labels just use "Computed Text"- Elements, but for contents (Dialog lists, option fields, etc) it is a little bit more complicated...

Comment: ok, computed text is the first thing I thought of. my fear was to slow down the workflow using dozens of computed text

Comment: Yes, it will slow down the app depending on how you do it. but computed texts are only a problem if there are 100 or more per form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop database with a multilingual design. To do that, you have to create a copy of every form in all languages you intend to support. In the Database Properties box, 4th tab (Design), select Multilingual database at the bottom, and you can set some defaults. In the Forms view, click the form, and in the Properties for the Form you can specify the language. The Notes client will pick the right form to display a document.

You can do the same with a View.

If there is a fast way to switch languages? I don't know, but don't think so. Your language preferences are stored in the Preferences in the Notes client.

Here's more info: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_PLANNING_FOR_TRANSLATING_AN_APPLICATION_STEPS.html